# Link of react-router-dom not working inside DataTable createdCell hook

Tags: jquery, reactjs, datatables, react-router-dom

1. I'm using jQuery DataTable inside react. (I know, not good to use jQuery in react but it's since long and many feature customize in that plug-in which we did not get in other plug-in)
2. Using columns hook we can add anchor link in one of column (it's working fine but page is refresh due to not use react router)

   ```
   let columnConfig = [
    ...ManyOtherColumns,
    {
     orderable: false,
     className: 'view-page-cell',
     "width": "35px",
     "defaultContent": "",
     "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
       //Some custom logic here...

       let anchor = `<a
         class="view-page"
         title="${title}"
         href="${url}">
           <img class="image" src="${viewIcon}" width="16" />
       </a>`;
       ReactDOM.render(anchor, td )
     }
    }
   ]
   ```
3. Not able to add `Link` of `react-router-dom` (using version "5.2.0") (code example as below), getting error like `Uncaught Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

   ```
    let columnConfig = [
    ...ManyOtherColumns,
    {
      orderable: false,
      className: 'view-page-cell',
      "width": "35px",
      "defaultContent": "",
      "createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
        // custom logic here.. 
        ReactDOM.render(<Link to={url} isactive="true" className="view-page"><img src="${viewIcon}" /></Link>, td )
      }
    }
   ]
   ```
4. DataTable Initialize as below

   ```
    wrapper.find('.data-table-grid').DataTable({ 
     ...OtherConfig,
     columns: columnConfig    
   });
   ```

**For more check my codepen:  https://codepen.io/jsnaghera/pen/vYrwgQz**

**NOTE:** Using click event on cell and `useHistory` will not full-fill my requirement because I need feature like user can righ+click and open page in new tab.

Comment: Are you *really* using React at all here? Can you edit the post to include a more complete [mcve] so it's clearer to us what, where, and how you are trying to add a link?

Comment: @DrewReese https://codepen.io/jsnaghera/pen/vYrwgQz

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to say it, but you will not be able use `react-router` inside of your jQuery code.

```
"createdCell": function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
     // custom logic here.. 
     ReactDOM.render(<Link to={url} isactive="true" className="view-page"><img src="${viewIcon}" /></Link>, td )
   }
```

When you call `ReactDOM.render` here you are creating a completely separate component tree. This `Link` will not be inside of the `Router` that's in your `App`.

---

The simplest solution is to use a standard `<a>` tag like `<a href="/view-page">`.  React-router will handle loading the correct content for that path.  But clicking this link will cause a full reload of the App rather than navigating inside the existing App instance like you would with a `<Link>`.

---

You can use `react-router` so long as you are not using an additional `ReactDOM.render`.

I came up with a solution where you use the `<Link>` in the code which *creates* the table markup, rather than where you modify the markup in jQuery.

I made a component that returns a `<td>`:

```
const LinkedCell = ({ children }) => (
  <td>
    <Link to="/view-page">
      <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5566/5566326.png" width="25" height="25" alt="" title="" className="img-small"/>
      {children}
    </Link>
  </td>
)
```

And then used that inside the `return` of your `App`:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <LinkedCell>Tiger Nixon</LinkedCell>
    <td>System Architect</td>
```

This eliminates your `columnDef`, so now you just need:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  $('#example').DataTable();
},[])
```

[**Revised CodePen**](https://codepen.io/linda-paiste/pen/bGjdqGR?editors=0010)

Comment: Is there any way to use with `ReactDom.render` because we have dynamic (JSON based) rendering. so it will take time to convert in this way and customize many feature. 

Is there any way to `<a href='/url'></a>` behave like `react-router` ?

Although, you given great solution. I appreciate it.

Comment: Re `<a>` behavior: You can call `useHistory` (or `useNavigate` in v6) at the top-level of the `App` component.  Create an event handler which uses the `history` from the hook to handle navigation.  Then use some pure JS (or jquery) to `addEventListener` to take over the click event on your `<a>` tags.  I haven't tested it but that should work.

Comment: Re `ReactDom.render`, you would need to render inside some sort of provider container which has access to your history and your routes.  You would have to look through the `react-router` docs and see if there's a way to create a `Router` that duplicates your main router.  Like can you define the react-router data outside of any components and then pass it to multiple router instances?  I know that you can do that with the `history` part via `createBrowserHistory` but I'm doubtful about the routes.

Comment: `<a>` behavior with event listener:  It will not fulfill my requirement of right click + open in new tab the page. seems I need to sacrifice something. :)

Comment: @JayeshNaghera I haven't played with it but it should be theoretically possible to set it up so that in the case of right-click or control-click it would behave as a normal link.  And apply the react-router override behavior only on a normal click.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `onClick` instead of `<a>` or `<Link>` then move page to your `URL` by that function.

```
<button onClick={YourFunctionName} />
```

Comment: Yes but please read the "NOTE" in my question.

Answer (score 0):

> ReactDOM.render() will not work with latest version. Creating a wrapper component will still not work because 'Link' is still outside Router. After React 17, useHistory won't work either. So your best solution is using useNavigate. You can create a button in datatables column and trigger navigate function on clicking that button. You can also pass your location state parameters just like Link in navigate function along with path. Here's a sample code. I just spent 5hours looking for an answer, finally figured it out myself.

```js
import React from "react";
import 'datatables.net-bs5'
import 'datatables.net'; // Import DataTables styles
import $ from "jquery";
import {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const users = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function renderMyData(data, type, row, meta) {
    if (type === 'display') {
      return (
        '<div class="col-12 text-center"><button type="button" class="table-buttonLink">+</button></div>'
      );
    }
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var t1 = $('#table1').DataTable()
    t1.destroy()
    t1 = $('#table1').DataTable({
      columnDefs: [
        //your code for other columns
        {
          targets: 7,
          render: (data, type, row, meta) => renderMyData(data, type, row, meta),
        }
      ],
      searching: false,
      order: [
        [1, 'asc']
      ],
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      paging: true,
      ajax: {
        url: 'your end point',
        method: 'GET',
      },
      columns: [{data: 'Name'},
        {data: 'Job'},
        {data: 'Salary'},
        {data: 'More'}
      ],
    });
    t1.on('click', '.table-buttonLink', async function() {
      var data = await t1.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
      navigate('moreInfo', {
        state: {
          from: data
        }
      })
    });
  })

  return ( <>
    <div className = "col-lg-12" >
      <div className = "container-fluid table table-responsive mb-4 text-secondary" >
        <table id = "table1" className = "table table-bordered table-hover" >
          <thead >
            <tr >
             <th className = "text-center" scope = "col" > # < /th>
             <th className = "text-center" scope = "col" > Name < /th>
             <th className = "text-center" scope = "col" > Job < /th>
             <th className = "text-center"scope = "col" > Salary < /th>
             <th className = "text-center" scope = "col" > More Info </th> 
           < /tr >
         </thead>
        < /table >
      </div>
    </div >
    </>
  )
}

export default users;
```